# Most efficient way to parse custom templates in PHP

Tags: php

Let's say we are writing a custom templating system and we would like a link to be displayed where template contains `{{link:http://example.com/something}}click here{{link}}`.

What will be the most optimal way to parse this?

Some approaches I can think of: Simple string manipulation using `substr`. Using `preg_replace` with back substitution etc.

Comment: Why writing another template system? Is there not enough of templating systems out there? Also, why need for templating system at all? Any templating other then use of pure PHP means more resources needed to parse the template, translate it to pure PHP and presentate it...

Comment: The "Let's say" makes me think you actually want to do something else, but dont want to share it. If changing links is the actual goal, just use BB code. It allows you to write [link=http..]click here[/link] which is basically just what you want, but with other tags

Comment: @shadyyx - it's not another template system. I just want to know the most effective way to achieve it. PHP documentation suggests to use string replacement for simple cases. But, at what point of time - it becomes not-so-simple?

Comment: @HugoDelsing Even in BBCode kind of scenario - what is most effective?

Comment: perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php can help. But for what you want you should use regex. A simple replacement would be [b]bold[/b] and then str_replace('[b]','<b>',$c); str_replace('[/b]','</b>',$c);. You cant use that here because there is no way to simply identify the }} between the link and click here. You cant just replace '}}' because it might also be used in a tag like {{page:/home}}homepage{{page}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my own parser, i'm using a mixture of "strpos / substr" and preg_replace. Why? well, its all in the numbers.

If your string to parse, contains alsmost only a {{link}} tag, without Start- & Endnoice, preg_replace is quicker e.g.

```
STARTNOICE{{link:http://example.com/something}}click here{{link}}ENDNOICE
```

But, the more characters are in Endnoice, the slower preg_replace is, compared to substr / strpos :)
Just 100 characters in Endnoice, will make substr / strpos being quicker than preg_match!

The best way to proof this, is with code ofcause. So here is a testscript. It compares the sum of time for substr with preg_match

Even though substr requires way more code, it is more efficient :)

Greetz,
JB

p.s. some results:

```
Startnoice = Endnoice = 100, /w 100 loops
$substrTime:
0.004448 Seconds
$pregTime:
0.004752 Seconds
```

.

```
Startnoice = Endnoice = 1000, /w 100 loops
$substrTime:
0.005598 Seconds
$pregTime:
0.023844 Seconds  << waaaay slower
```

.

```
Startnoice = Endnoice = 10000, /w 100 loops
$substrTime:
0.009028 Seconds
$pregTime:
0.278836 Seconds  << Dont use preg_replace
```

.

```
<?PHP
$startNoice = 1;
$endNoice   = 100;

for( $jb = 0; $jb < 100; $jb++ )
{
    $string = randomgenerator( $startNoice ) . '{{link:http://example.com/something}}click here{{link}}.' . randomgenerator( $endNoice );

/**************/
// Strpos / substr
/**************/

/* Start the timer */
    $Start = '{{link:';
    $StartEnd = '}}';
    $Stop = '{{link}}';

    $StartLen = strlen( $Start );
    $StartEndLen = strlen( $StartEnd );
    $StopLen = strlen( $Stop );

    $time_start = microtime_float();
    $strpos['Start']    = strpos( $string, $Start );

    $start = substr( $string, 0, $strpos['Start']);
    $end = substr( $string, $strpos['Start'] );

    $strpos['StartEnd'] = strpos( $end, $StartEnd, $StartLen );
    $strpos['Stop']     = strpos( $end, $Stop, $StartLen );

    $url  = substr( $end, $strpos['Start'] + $StartLen, ($strpos['StartEnd'] - $strpos['Start'] - $StartLen)  );
    $text = substr( $end, $strpos['StartEnd'] + $StartEndLen, ($strpos['Stop'] - $strpos['StartEnd'] - $StartEndLen) );

// Replace the link
    $NewString1 = $start . '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $text . '</a>' . substr( $end, $strpos['Stop'] + $StopLen );
/* Stop the tumer */
    $time_end = microtime_float();
    $substrTime[] = $time_end - $time_start;


/**************/
// Preg_match
/**************/
    $time_start = microtime_float();
    $NewString2 = preg_replace('/{{link:(.*)}}(.*){{link}}/', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $string);
    $time_end = microtime_float();
    $pregTime[] = $time_end - $time_start;
}

echo '$substrTime: . <br />';
echo round( array_sum( $substrTime ), 6) . ' Seconds';
echo '<br />';
echo '$pregTime: . <br />';
echo round( array_sum( $pregTime ), 6) . ' Seconds';

function randomgenerator( $length )
{
    $string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}][|\::",./';
    $r = '';
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ )
    {
        $r .= $string[ rand(0, strlen( $string ) -1 ) ];
    }
    return $r;
}

function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
?>
```

Comment: But how would it turn out if you where also looking for similar tags where 'link' could also be page, image, font, span, div etc? Then you need a seperate function for each strpos which eventually will make it slower, because with preg_match you can get all of them in one go and then switch the tag you got back. Another problem would be nested tags. That wont work.

Comment: preg_match and nested tags are a pian in the.... whilst substring can handle it quite easily: you first search for the last last closing tag in the code, and then search the last opening tag in the code b4 the closing tag: works really nice and quick. If you want to replace other tags, besides link, you also need other replacement code: so yes, you would need to alter the replace function. But, there is no need to create a new function for each code... Using purely preg_replace in your template parser is easy, but it is, with larger files, slow.

Comment: I ment running the same code several times for each tag, which would make it slower (time * nr of tags). Your provide a valid solution, but i'm not convinced with the speed factor. I dont think somebody would parse 100 large templates every page request. Perhaps 1 for each page request, but that would mean the time difference would be some miliseconds. In that case I think an easy solution is better then a slightly faster one

Comment: It all depends... If you have a complex preg_replace, most certainly it can be done quicker with other code. A valid example is the link code above that IS quicker than preg_replace. If however you have a simple preg_match, lets say you want to replace "{{bold}}" with "<b>" than yes, preg_replace is quite optimized. The above example parses 100 "pages" just to give a better understandable time ofcause... mostly a templateparse parses 2-4 files. For the milisecond part, yes, we are talking about unnoticable times, but you asked for the "most efficient way", remmeber? :) JB

Comment: I didnt, but you are right. And no matter if the speed issue applies, it still a valid awnser. +1